# Aerospike Replication Without Persistence

Tags: cluster-computing, aerospike, distributed-caching, nosql

Will an in-memory only Aerospike cluster composed of n nodes automatically replicate data across nodes, and in this case, is there a guarantee that no data will be written to disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will an in-memory only Aerospike cluster composed of n nodes automatically replicate data across nodes?

Yes, assuming you are talking about `storage-engine memory` and not `storage-engine device` with `data-in-memory true`.

> And in this case, is there a guarantee that no data will be written to disk?

Your records will not be written to disk. Logs and SMD (system meta data) will be written to disk.

Comment: Thank you. Is this also the case for XDR? Assuming that I have 2 in-memory only clusters, composed of n nodes, situated in 2 separate data centers, will no data be written to disk during cross data center replication?

Comment: @PaulMooney With XDR some data may be written. XDR logs transactions, then combines and ships them. But it is possible to set a limit to the file size of the digest log. [In this link](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/xdr.html) you can find more details on how XDR works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Aerospike uses Smart Partition algorithm using RIPEMD160 which takes care of even data distribution and replication across the cluster. If replication factor is configured correctly, it will distribute data correctly/evenly in the cluster.
2. Only in Persistence mode Aerospike expects to be provided a disk storage file to persist the data into. If Aerospike is configured for In-Memory storage, there is no option of providing disk storage file which essentially means it does not persist the data to the disk.

namespace testreplication {

```
# memory-size 4G           # 4GB of memory to be used for index and data
# replication-factor 2     # For multiple nodes, keep 2 copies of the data
# high-water-memory-pct 60 # Evict non-zero TTL data if capacity exceeds
                           # 60% of 4GB
# stop-writes-pct 90       # Stop writes if capacity exceeds 90% of 4GB
# default-ttl 0            # Writes from client that do not provide a TTL
                           # will default to 0 or never expire
# storage-engine memory    # Store data in memory only
```

}